# SQL Server : ALTER TABLE, ALTER COLUMN - Change column length

Tags: sql-server

I have created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse 
(
    Code INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    location NVARCHAR(50), 
    Capacity INT
)

CREATE TABLE Boxes  
(
    Code NVARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, 
    contents NVARCHAR(50), 
    Value REAL, 
    warehouse INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES warehouse(code)
)
```

Now I'm trying to change the length of the column `Boxes.Code` using the following statement:

```
ALTER COLUMN Code NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
```

But I get

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Code failed because one or more objects
>   access this column.

Comment: You may have to first drop the table and recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. You should never define a constraint without giving it a name. Your Primary Keys will have cryptic random names...
2. A PK should ever be given to a NOT NULL column!
3. As long as the primary key is using this column you cannot change it
4. So you must drop the constraint
5. Then you can change your column
6. Then you can recreate your constraint

So: This should work, but you'll need to adapt it...

```
create table Warehouse(Code int not null constraint pk_warehouse primary key
                      ,location nvarchar(50)
                      ,Capacity int);
GO
create table Boxes(Code nvarchar not null constraint pk_boxes primary key
                  ,contents nvarchar (50)
                  ,Value real
                  ,warehouse int foreign key references warehouse(code));
GO

alter table Boxes drop constraint pk_boxes;
alter table Boxes alter column code nvarchar (20) not null;
alter table Boxes add constraint pk_boxes primary key(Code);
GO

--clean up
drop table Boxes;
GO
drop table Warehouse;
GO
```

Comment: @Mojtaba, glad, that this could help you. Please vote helpful answers up and mark the one which helped you most as accepted (the check below the vote counter). This will show to the others, that this question is solved and make me happy, if I get the reputation points ;-)

Comment: @Mojtaba, hi I want to invite you once again to mark the most helpful answer as accepted. I just pushed you a little... Once you've got 15 reputation points you may vote on posts - and you really should... And please look over your othere question too to mark the accepted solution, thx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either drop the PK constraint, alter the column size, and then re-add the constraint (btw naming your constraints rather than using system named constraints makes this a lot easier).
Example:

```
ALTER TABLE Boxes DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Boxes__A25C5AA6647CBF9C;
alter table boxes alter column code nvarchar (20) not null;
alter table boxes ADD CONSTRAINT PK__Boxes__A25C5AA6647CBF9C PRIMARY KEY (Code);
```